# How to change the value of my model's primary key?

Tags: python, sqlite, data-modeling, peewee

I have a peewee model using a custom-set non-integer primary key:

```
class User(BaseModel):
    email = CharField(primary_key=True)
    full_name = CharField()

    # other properties go here
```

Now, some users have got incorrectly saved so I have to update their email addresses. However, running a simple `save` does not work:

```
>>> u = User.get(email='wrong@bad.is')
>>> u.email = 'correct@good.is'
>>> u.save()
```

This returns `0` and does not do anything. Short of deleting the old record and creating a new one, is there any way to update the primary key value?

**Note:** This is a one-time operation due to bad data import. As a general rule, email addresses are not going to be updated, which is why they're being used as a primary key

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just realised I can use an `update` query:

```
User.update(email='correct@good.is').where(User.email == 'wrong@bad.is').execute()
```

Replace `.execute()` with `.sql()` to print the raw SQL command instead of actually executing the update.